# Keys getting stuck

Tags: windows-vista, keyboard

I am running a desktop with Vista.

At random points when typing I will press a key, the key will stick. I will get multiple keypressesssssssssssssssssss. (for example what just happened at the end of that last word!)

Any ideas what is causing this? I dont even know where to start looking here..

**EDIT**

Ok, have been trying a new keyboard and it hasnt made any difference. Still the same problem.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Is it a wireless keyboard or normal USB keyboard ?

Comment: It is a normal USB.

Comment: Turn on stickykeys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if using usb port, try different port. make sure there is no mapping on your mouse to enter anything either. you can program mouse buttons/actions to do stuff and you might have an "s" in clipboard and you are executing the paste "button"

Comment: Ah yes.. Different USB port is an obvious one I should have thought of myself! Trying now..

Comment: Yup, had no stuck keys for several days now. Mustve been a dodgy usb port! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Randy.  Had the exact same problem and it was the USB port.

Comment: Had this problem with my wireless keyboard when it was attached to a USB hub. Moved the USB dongle to a port directly on the computer, and it works fine now.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a mechanical problem with the keyboard - i.e., the 'S' key is literally sticking down and then eventually releasing. I once had a problem when a grain of instant coffee lodged between two keys and stuck them together, so that a press on either typed both characters...

Over time, keyboards get very dirty inside as crap falls between the keys. If the problem is with one key specifically, you can probably solve this by popping the key top off ***gently*** with something like a car key and cleaning out any gunk underneath (the key top will fit back on with a firm press). Make sure that key rises cleanly when you release it.

You may need to clean the whole keyboard. A start would be to hold it upside down and shake it gently - you may be surprised by what falls out. Better to do this with the keyboard disconnected, of course.

In the final analysis, keyboards do fail eventually and aren't expensive to replace.

Comment: Im not sure if it this problem as the problem is not related to any particular key or even any area of the keyboard.. it can happen with any key..

Comment: @Pongus: keyboards are reasonably complex beasts, there're a lot of points of failure - not just the keys.

Comment: Good point. Not sure why Im so keen to instantly blame Vista for the fault!

Answer (score 3):

Just try another keyboard to see if the problem comes from your keyboard or not. This should be the first thing to try before deciding what to try next.

Comment: On the case!!!!

Comment: Sorry, what does "on the case" mean? Aren't you using a separate keyboard?

Comment: I mean that I am going to try a new keyboard. I think the term comes from detective novels. A crime is called "a case" and when the detective would start investigating the crime, they would say there were "on the case".

Comment: :) Sorry, I misunderstood. I can't help myself thinking about a "PC case" when I hear that word!

Comment: If you're having the same problem with multiple keys, I would still guess that it's a keyboard fault - just a more complex and less curable one. Try a good keyboard. If the fault disappears, buy a new keyboard - you probably can't fix the fault economically even if you can trace it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried playing with the value for **Repeat Delay** in the `Keyboard > Speed settings`. Set it to longest and see what happens. Change it notch by notch back until you find that strange bug occurring again, then obviously go down one.

My laptop has an issue where sometimes the repeat delay becomes too long, moving the slider back and forth then saving the changes resets this bug.

[image: it's all a little bit voodoo]

Comment: Interesting suggestion. Worth knowing! Will try this after the different USB port fails..